# Ternary graph programming to retrieve the data

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, graph, ternary

I need help regarding a ternary graph programming what the idea is:

A colorful triangle that has the word "Finances" in one corner, "Freedom" in another, and "Fulfillment" in the last corner. The user should be able to use their mouse cursor to hover over the triangle. Below the cursor should be a little bubble or dot that follows the cursor. When the mouse is clicked, the bubble or dot should stick to that location on the ternary graph.

The user should be able to click in a new location to move the bubble if they so choose, but once they get satisfied with their location, they click a button on the side that says, "Click for your customized success blend" Following the clicking of this button, numbers should appear beside the three words with the actual data points for each of the three factors (see attached image for further clarity).

I need this to implement in wordpress.

[image]

Comment: So what have you tried? Does not seem that complicated using SVG for the drawing.

Comment: How to implement, i am new to this. Doing this first time. :)
Right now i am researching on Internet.

Comment: 1) Create the background picture. 2) Apply a mousemove event to the picture. In the event read mouseposition and do your output accordingly. 3) Add a click event: Removing the moving event, updating the data. 4) Do the rest of the logic ...